# Динамическое обновление данных в RecyclerView из другого потока

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, у меня есть UI поток, в нем отображается RecyclerView, и есть другой поток, в нем грузятся файлы, так вот, по мере загрузки файла я обновляю процент загруженных данных файла в ArrayList, который работает с Adapter'om. Мне нужно чтобы в UI потоке эти обновления сразу же отображались. Пробовал через notifyDataSetChanged() в adapter'e и в UI потоке тоже пробовал, все вроде бы работало, но с дикими лагами и обновлялись значения только при скролинге. Может кто-нибудь что подсказать как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, да костыль, но другого путного не придумал.
Начал обновлять данные на прямую, так как у меня ProgressBar, то объявлял его:
В классе Активности:

```
public static void updateProgress(int position, int percent){
       ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) recyclerView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
       progressBar.setProgress(percent);
    }
```